# * operator overloading with template class

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, g++, operator-keyword

Trying to achieve Matrix multiplication through overloaded * operator with class templates.The code works on CodeBlocks (with some warnings) in Windows ,but while compiling through g++ in Ubuntu it shows some issues.Furthurmore running the './a.out' yields segmentation fault.

```
#include <iostream>
#define TOLERANCE 0.0001

using namespace std;

template <class T>class Matrix;
template <class T>ostream &operator<<(ostream &out,const Matrix<T>&);
//Matrix can be of any data type
template <class T> Matrix<T> &operator*( Matrix<T>&);
template <class T>
class Matrix{
    private:
        int rows,columns;
        T **A;
    public:
        //Default Constructor
        Matrix(){rows=0;columns=0;}
        //Parameterised Constructor
        Matrix(int Rows,int Cols){
        rows=Rows;
        columns=Cols;
        A=new T*[rows];
        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
            A[i]=new T[columns];
        }
        void displayMatrix();
        void fillMatrix(T x);
        Matrix<T>& operator* ( Matrix<T> &X);//Matrix Multiply
        friend ostream &operator<< <T>(ostream &out ,const Matrix<T> &X);

};
template <class T>
void Matrix<T>::displayMatrix(){
    for(int i=0;i<rows ;i++ ){
        for(int j=0 ;j<columns ;j++ )
            cout<<A[i][j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
        }
    }

template <class T>
void Matrix<T>::fillMatrix(T x){
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<columns; j++)
            A[i][j]=x;
}

template <class T>
Matrix<T> &Matrix<T>::operator*(  Matrix<T> &X){
    T sum=0;
    if(columns=X.rows){
        Matrix<T> Q(rows,X.columns);
        for(int i=0; i<rows ;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<X.columns; j++){
                for(int k=0 ;k<columns ;k++ )
                    sum+=A[i][k]*(X.A[k][j]);
                Q.A[i][j]=sum;
                sum=0;
                }
            }
            return Q;
        }else{
        cout<<"Something's wrong!";
        return *this;
        }
    }

int main(){
Matrix<double> x,y,z;
x.fillMatrix(1.2);
y.fillMatrix(2.3);
z=x*y;
z.displayMatrix();
return 0;
}
```

I want to achieve Matrix Multiplication for generalized template in cpp.
This yields the following  :

> myProj.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Matrix& Matrix::operator*(Matrix&) [with T = int]’:
>   myProj.cpp:75:5:   required from here
>   myProj.cpp:52:13: warning: reference to local variable ‘Q’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
>      Matrix Q(rows,X.columns);

Comment: Warnings are almost always equally important to fix as errors. They are often a sign of you doing something unexpected and that could lead to undefined behavior when running.

Comment: By the way, where is the templated class?

Comment: Pasted the wrong code segment before..edited it now..please have a look..can you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables, or variables in nested scopes, disappear once they go out of scope. For example, in your `operator*` function you have the local variable `Q`. When you return from the function, the variable no longer exists, and the `Q` object will be destructed. Returning a reference to it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The problem here isn't actually returning `Q` but that you return *by reference*. The solution is to return *by value*. It's the same for the `operator+` overloaded function, it should also return by value.

Returning by value of course requires you to follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which you don't do now since you don't have any assignment operator, copy- or move-constructors, or even a destructor (the last which will lead to memory leaks).

Comment: hello,                   By mistake I pasted the wrong code segment...edited it...can you please go through it again and post your valuable comments?

Comment: @ArghaChakraborty It's still the same problem, that you return by reference instead of by value. You also have the same problem with missing copy-constructor, assignment operator and destructor. If you follow [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) you don't need them, but for that you can't use dynamic memory allocation. (`std::vector` is a very good replacement).

Comment: Thank you so much.